# iOS project doesn't reference a static library from Binding project when in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, binding, xamarin.ios, mono, static-libraries

I've got a static library, which was used to generate the wrapping code by Sharpie. The library was Built after that (including, generated *.dll) successfully.

AppDefinition.cs contains the namespace and the mappings, like this:

```
namespace TheNamespace
{
    // @interface TheParameters : NSObject
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface TheParameters
    {
```

The library itself built in Release mode with `LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Arm64`.

However, when referencing this binding project from my iOS project, it works only in Debug mode.
When I change it to `Release`, **the namespace (and all the related clasees) not available**. **Also, when** exploring the binding library reference in **Object Browser**, it doesn't display any elements: it's totally empty.

Just to point that: it gets available when changing it in the dropdown to `Debug` and disappears on `Release`, what's interesting, *undependently on what actually project is selected in Current Project dropdown*!

What might be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi , you need to check whehter the static library supports release mode when generating .Maybe it only builds below debug mode .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some Googling I found the solution.
The issue happens because of Visual Studio bug, I guess. And also referred [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4315). (And it's weird it's not mentioned in Xamarin docs on Microsoft website.

To resolve the issue **the Binding Project(s) must not reside in the same solution with the main project**. Just remove them and attach the library as regular reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem should come from when building static library .When generating static library , there is a build type of release/debug to select.

[image]

Above screenshot shows static library types after building , there are three types (Two is Debug and One is Release ). You can see that tt distinguishes between release and debug .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However... not really. 1. It seems like you have an XCode lbrary project, which is not my case. What I am having is a Visual Studio Binding Project (on Windows), which includes only *.a file and corresponding ApiDefinition.cs. So as output it has only Debug and Release folders with *.dll and *.pdb files. 2. Even when using Release output *.dll in main iOS project, it allows attaching it in Debug mode only.

Comment: Actually, found the solution.

Comment: @Agat Great ,got it ! Glad find the solution.It's a good question for us .